# Is "appeal" the correct word in "Without appeal to the C-principle"

Tags: word-choice

Is 'appeal' the correct word in:

> Method A solves Problem B without appeal to the C-principle.

This sentence tries to say that there is an obvious solution to Problem B that can be found using a very general principle C, but method A is actually a more specialized method tailored to Problem B that is found without using the general solution principle C.

I feel like I am confusing 'appeal' with the similar sounding correct word, since I do know of usages of 'appeal to' that are different from the one I intend (e.g. 'it had no appeal to him').

I couldn't find my intended usage in dictionary entries for 'appeal'

Comment: What dictionary did you use? Look at the second sense of both the noun and verb as provided by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appeal). (If using the noun, you would need **an appeal**.)

Comment: @Jason I used the Cambridge dictionary https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/appeal?q=Appeal now that I know I was right I can interpret some of the senses there in the way I intended but with the way those senses translated in my head to my native language they didn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

It is correct but I would prefer "without appealing to the C-principle".

See for example [a stack exchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272867/axiom-of-choice-in-set-theory)

> Of course, there are certain specific instances where one can do this without appealing to the Axiom of Choice:
>
> - if you only have to make finitely many choices; or
> - if these choices can be made in a uniform manner

Comment: I happen to also need this for a math manuscript. I guess that's where I picked up the phrase in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You say you might be confusing *appeal* with a similar-sounding word. I'm guessing that word is *apply*:

> Method A solves Problem B without **applying** the C-principle.

Here, [*apply*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/apply) would mean:

> **apply** (*verb*) To put to use; to use or employ for a particular purpose

[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/apply) defines it as:

> **apply** (*verb*)  to use a particular method, process, law, etc.